# JQuery Method affecting the Direct children only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please find the link below, to the fiddle I have created.

[**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/dcJbX/1/)

This is a simple Jquery animation. When the mouse enters the "Yellow color div", the "Red div" scales up giving an zooming effect. But since the div's are made of single class in CSS, Hovering on one div affects all the other divs. Now I want this to happen only on div, on which the mouse enters not affecting others. Please guide. And let me  know if it is possible without repeating the code for all 3 divs.

What have I done so far:

```
//Image Scale Up Animation  
box.mouseenter(function () {
    $('.frame').removeClass("normal").addClass("scale");
});

//Image Scale Down Animation    
box.mouseleave(function () {
     $('.frame').removeClass("scale").addClass("normal");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the element `.frame` which is inside hovered div. You should use :

```
box.mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.frame').removeClass("normal").addClass("scale");
});


//Image Scale Down Animation    
box.mouseleave(function () {
     $(this).find('.frame').removeClass("scale").addClass("normal");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KfZ8G/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may use [**children([selector])**](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
var box = $('.box');

//Image Scale Up Animation  
box.mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).children('.frame').removeClass("normal").addClass("scale");
});


//Image Scale Down Animation    
box.mouseleave(function () {
     $(this).children('.frame').removeClass("scale").addClass("normal");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcJbX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the children of your selected element.

See the following code :

```
var box = $('.box');

//Image Scale Up Animation  
box.mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).children().removeClass("normal").addClass("scale");
});


//Image Scale Down Animation    
box.mouseleave(function () {
     $(this).children().removeClass("scale").addClass("normal");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find frame from the current object using $(this).

```
//Image Scale Up Animation  
$('.box').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.frame').removeClass("normal").addClass("scale");
}).mouseleave(function() {
//Image Scale Down Animation
    $(this).find('.frame').removeClass("scale").addClass("normal");
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saorabh/dcJbX/4/)

In above example on mouseenter, we need to find the current frame and on mouseleave to reset the animation.